# Betta lying on bottom of tank?

Tags: betta

thanks for reading this article! I am currently treating my Betta in a 1 gallon tank that I float in his usual tank, a 10 gallon planted with a nerite snail and nothing else. He just lies flat at the bottom of the tank with one eye looking up, so on his side, he is breathing but I don’t think he will make it for long, I don’t know what it is. I am treating him for fin rot with King British fin rot and fungus control. It is heated to 26.4 Celsius and I do a 2-3 gallon water change every week. Please help, his name it buddy. Thank you.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of another question. If you think that your question is different to that one in some way, please edit your question and explain how it differs. Good luck with buddy :)

Comment: I woke up today and he was dead :’(

Comment: Sorry to hear - it's always tough! If you plan on getting another one I'd urge you to read the resources here, the duplicate I linked to and ask any questions about things you still have doubts about. I love keeping fish but the worst I've ever felt during my early days was when I realised I made a costly mistake which I could have prevented if I knew the basics (although I'm sure you know them) :)